# How to using simple_form association no data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

Guys.

How to I do to using "association" of the simple_form gem, but do not want load data. I need of the field empty.

Comment: Why do you want the field empty? Do you want the user to type something in?

Comment: I have 2 select fields and the second is loaded when the first is selected. Then in the start the second field should be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

f.association :company, :collection => [""]